# MATLAB event and infinite sleeping or checking loop

Tags: events, matlab, event-handling, infinite-loop

I need to perform data analysis on files in a directory as they come in.

I'd like to know, if it is better,

1. to implement an event listener on the directory, and start the analysis process when activated. Then having the program go into sleep forever: `while(true), sleep(1e10), end`
2. or to have a loop polling for changes and reacting.

I personally prefer the listeners way, as one is able to start the analysis twice on two new files coming in NEARLY the same time but resulting in two events. While the other solution might just handle the first one and after that finds the second new data.
Additional idea for option 1: Hiding the matlab GUI by calling `frames=java.awt.Frame.getFrames` and setting `frames(index).setVisible(0)` on the `index` matching the `com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLMainFrame`-frame. (This idea is taken from [Yair Altman](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/))

Are there other ways to realize such things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, (if you are using Windows), the best way is to use the power of `.NET`.

```
fileObj = System.IO.FileSystemWatcher('c:\work\temp');
fileObj.Filter = '*.txt';
fileObj.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
addlistener(fileObj,'Changed',@eventhandlerChanged);
```

There are different event types, you can use the same callback for them, or different ones:

```
addlistener(fileObj, 'Changed', @eventhandlerChanged );
addlistener(fileObj, 'Deleted', @eventhandlerChanged );
addlistener(fileObj, 'Created', @eventhandlerChanged );
addlistener(fileObj, 'Renamed', @eventhandlerChanged );
```

Where `eventhandlerChanged` is your callback function.

```
function eventhandlerChanged(source,arg)
   disp('TXT file changed')
end
```

There is no need to use `sleep` or polling. If your program is UI based, then there is nothing else to do, when the user closes the figure, the program has ended. The event callbacks are executed exactly like button clicks. If your program is script-like, you can use an infinite loop.

More info in here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/working-with-net-events-in-matlab.html

Comment: Indeed, that was, what I proposed to do buy option number 1 - but as this should be a script, should it wait forever? Maybe, this is an idea - but then it is open for inputs...

Comment: @BastianEbeling: your program will be event-driven (execute your data analysis from inside the callback function). nice solution btw +1

Comment: @Andrey: from what i understand, this only fires on file changes, not addition/deletion of files, right? you need to listen to those events too

Comment: @Amro, there is another event for addition/deletion. Usually I use the same callback for them. I updated my answer

Comment: Hi @Amro and Andrey, your ideas (I ment by my option 1) are fine. Further, is there a chance to leave those listeners active and end all other matlab interactive things?  Maybe removing the input-device or something like that? I start matlab now with "-automation", but maybe there are better alternatives?