# How to find latestly added file in a folder by MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab, file-io

Suppose there is a download of images going on and I have a code that process each given image. I want to find the latently downloaded image in a folder and process it next. How can I find that lastly downloaded image in that folder via Matlab code?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility:

```
% get a list of .txt files inside folder. You can specify images instead
d = dir('*.txt');

% find the last modified file
[~,idx] = max([d.datenum]);

% name of file
filename = d(idx).name;
```

Another way is to listen to file system changes and respond to events as new files come in. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10915784/97160) for an example.

The first method would be used with [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29), the second is [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).